# How to read a HTTP network request over a socket in C#?

Tags: c#

I am attempting to read an http request over a socket and am unable to read until the end. Is there someone that can help me out?

```
IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[0];
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
    
Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
listener.Listen(1);

Socket networkRequestHandler = listener.Accept();
NetworkStream myNetworkStream = new NetworkStream(networkRequestHandler);
           
byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
StringBuilder myCompleteMessage = new StringBuilder();
int numberOfBytesRead = myNetworkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
    
while (numberOfBytesRead != 0){
    myCompleteMessage.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
    numberOfBytesRead = myNetworkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
}
```

Comment: Http client's don't close the connection, you need to parse the content until you receive `\n\n`.

Comment: Is this some form of exercise in masochism? Leaning on an existing implementation of an HTTP client or server is almost always a better use of ones time than trying to re-implement it yourself.

Comment: Is this homework? If not, this won't work as HTTP can use many encodings and almost everyone uses UTF8, not the 7-bit US-ASCII encoding. This is less efficient than the built-in classes too, because it allocates a lot of temporary strings.

Comment: why reinvent the wheel, check signalR https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever good stuff, nah.. just looking to broaden my paint strokes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working C# console application. The server I chose responds with a redirect trying to get us to use HTTPS instead of HTTP. However the socket works as intended and demonstrates sending a request and receiving the response. If you can find a server that is still responding via HTTP (instead of requiring HTTPS) you'll get a 200 response probably with HTML.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var hostName = "stackoverflow.com";
    var ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
    var ipAddress = ipHostEntry.AddressList.First();
    var ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 80);

    using (var socket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
    {
        // Short timeout to connect and receive, for testing.
        var timeout = 5000;

        try
        {
            IAsyncResult result = socket.BeginConnect(ipEndpoint, null, null);

            if (result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout, true))
                socket.EndConnect(result);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        // If we couldn't connect from exception or otherwise, return.
        if (!socket.Connected)
            return;

        // Format the message as a standard HTTP request.
        var message = $"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {hostName}\r\nAccept: text/html\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\n\r\n";
        var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        var receiveBuffer = new byte[1024];

        int bytesReceived;

        socket.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
        socket.Send(messageBytes, messageBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);

        try
        {
            using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                // Loop until all the data is received.
                while (true)
                {
                    bytesReceived = socket.Receive(receiveBuffer, receiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);

                    stream.Write(receiveBuffer, 0, bytesReceived);

                    if (bytesReceived != receiveBuffer.Length)
                        break;

                    // Don't loop too quickly.
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
                }

                // When finished receiving the data, write it out as text.
                var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());

                Console.WriteLine(response);
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        socket.Close();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: im going to give you the answer considering it lead me to the right direction which was using the httplistener. its great! thank you.