# c# Socket tcp/ip not reading ACK

Tags: c#, sockets

I am connected with a socket, which has been working well for many years, to a medical device which sends me an ACK but I cannot read it. I see it with Wireshark but not inside the code.
I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863101/how-can-i-verify-that-a-tcp-packet-has-received-an-ack-in-c) and other posts, but they don't help me.
I've read that there are known problems reading ACKs in Tcp/Ip packets but haven't found any recommendations or solutions.
In the communication with the instrument I have to wait to receive ACK to continue and therefore I'm blocked because instead of receiving ACK this error occurs:
**Unable to establish connection. Incorrect response from the connected party after the time interval or no response from the connected host.**
I only insert the Read method because I don't think there are any problems with the rest of the code which works fine, I can send ACK but not receive it.
Someone told me to use PcapDotNet but I don't understand how to do it.
**EDIT:
I just tested the COM Port Data Emulator program and I receive the ACK sent to me by the program. I really don't understand why I don't get the one of the medical instrument.**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace myCom
{

public partial class SocketLan
{

    private Socket oClientSocket;

    public SocketLan(string cIp, int nPort)
    {

        try
        {
            this.oClientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            if (this.Connect(cIp, nPort))
            {
                this.oClientSocket.SendTimeout = 5000;
                this.oClientSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
            }
        }
        catch 
        {
            this.oClientSocket.Close();
        }
    }

    public bool Connect(string cIp, int nPort)
    {
        bool lOk;
        IAsyncResult ar;

        ar = this.oClientSocket.BeginConnect(cIp, nPort, null, null);
        try
        {
            if (!ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), false))
            {
                throw new TimeoutException();
            }
            this.oClientSocket.EndConnect(ar);
            lOk = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            lOk = false;
        }

        return lOk;
    }

    public string Read(int nRead = 1024)
    {
        string cReturnData = "";
        byte[] InStream;
        int nByte;

        if (this.oClientSocket.Connected)
        {
            InStream = new byte[nRead];

            try
            {
                nByte = this.oClientSocket.Receive(InStream, 0, nRead, SocketFlags.None);//Here it goes wrong
                if (nByte > 0)
                {
                    cReturnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(InStream, 0, nByte);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cReturnData = "";
                string cError = ex.Message;//This is the error!
                return cReturnData;
            }
        }

        return cReturnData;
    }


   }

   }
```

Comment: what does Wireshark say is going on

Comment: a reminder, that read is not guaranteed to read the 'whole message' whatever that might mean

Comment: I don't know where to start... does the start of the problems coincide with anything else? I see a lot to do, but nothing that obviously would cause the perceived behavior. Did the other device get new software?

Comment: For starters you should take that Connect() out of your constructor, it's bad to have it there and you connect again later anyway. However I don't think that's your issue. Are you sure you can just connect to the server and start reading? With most protocols you need to send something first. My guess is you are hitting the 5 second timeout. I just posted an example of an HTTP request/response using pure sockets, if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75893634/how-to-read-a-http-network-request-over-a-socket-in-c/75894899#75894899

Comment: @Fildor, The other device is an old tool with Windows NT and hasn't been updated, this is me attempting to connect for the first time.

Comment: @pm100 Great idea, I didn't know about Wireshark, I've downloaded it now and will try it as soon as I can

Comment: ACK is an implementation detail of the TCP protocol, you will not see it in your own code.  Other than that the Receive() call is likely to complete and your program continues running.  You are probably asking this question because of the nRead parameter of your Read() method, it is not a subtle detail.  Crucial about TCP is that it implements a *stream*, not a packet-oriented connection.  In other words, you cannot predict how many bytes you'll receive.  Take a closer look at the data, there ought to be a way to tell that the data transmission is complete.  Perhaps a line-feed character.

Comment: Please add the Manufacturer and model of the device to your OP. Have you referred to the documentation for the medical device to determine the expected message format as another commenter mentioned?

Comment: @user09938 The manufacturer is Siemens and the model is ADVIA 2120, no format is specified, just the composition of the message. From other tools I always receive ACKs without any problems. Thanks.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Communication Links Between the Data Manager and a Host Computer](http://startrinity3.com/01/Advia%20Comms%20Links.pdf)

Comment: @user09938 the document of your post is obsolete, the instrument now is of the Siemens and not Bayer. I have the latest version and it doesn't help.

Comment: If you have a copy of the documentation that discusses the message structure, then your 70% toward achieving your goal. No one here will be able to assist you without having access to the information in that document. To determine the version of the document that one needs to use start by locating the date of manufacture of the device. The device should have a label on it indicating the date of manufacture as well as the name of the manufacturer which may (or may not) be different from who currently manufactures the device. Obviously one also needs to determine if the device has been updated.